# Git Hooks: remote repository should accept push, only if commit message contents particular string

Tags: git, githooks

I am writing update hook on server side. I have succesfully done and restricted.
1. File size
2. File extensions
What I want to do now, to check message and accept only if that contents string, say "INFO:".

I have checked with `git log` in `update` hook, but it gives already accepted results only.
What should I do to check message before accepting/pushing changes into repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this site from the official git website: [Customizing Git - An Example Git-Enforced Policy](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy)

It has a use-case that is very much like yours. Specifically this part:

```bash
$regex = /\[ref: (\d+)\]/

# enforced custom commit message format
def check_message_format
  missed_revs = `git rev-list #{$oldrev}..#{$newrev}`.split("\n")
  missed_revs.each do |rev|
    message = `git cat-file commit #{rev} | sed '1,/^$/d'`
    if !$regex.match(message)
      puts "[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly"
      exit 1
    end
  end
end
check_message_format
```